# No boot option after installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Acer Aspire 4736z with Live CD

Tags: 12.04, grub2, system-installation, lts

I am facing a problem. After installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Live CD, at the reboot there is no boot option to choose the OS. I directly get logged into my Windows 7.

Before that i was having an issue with the '**nomodeset**' if not mistaken .After ticking [x] on the **nomodeset**, i can install my Ubuntu, but got stucked again at choosing the partition option.

So i did 2 partitions for Ubuntu, 1 partition as **ext3** for **/** and the other 1 for **swap**. Which enabled to proceed until the finished  installation dialogue, and after that system wants to reboot .It takes some time and gets stuck at the screen doing nothing, doesn't reboot at all.

I did forced shutdown then rebooted again which directly logs me in windows 7 without boot option. In win7 the partitions for Ubuntu is gone.

I tried the boot-repair thing and it doesn't help .It just shows up the **_ Blank Cursor** (terminal thing i guess). I typed boot repair but still the same result.

I am using **Acer Aspire 4736z**.

Please somebody help me with this issue.

Comment: I apologize but I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Do you want to creat a dual boot installation where after starting your PC you get a list A=Ubuntu and B=Windows7 or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: did you followed the steps mentioned here ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair .. if so and its not working, post the url of boot summery (see here for instruction http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1821980)

Comment: yup. i try to make dual boot. and 1 partition for each os.

Comment: yes. i type the sudo thing. and it said no kernel found. sumting like tat.

Comment: for my win7 i had the part already. the new one i did was for ubuntu and its swap.

Comment: How can any one help you if are not mentioning clearly what is the problem.. that above step should be done from a live cd. and post the exact error

Comment: im apologize for the lack of information. later i will note down all the error i get.sorry again.

Comment: If you had (or have still) the same problem, you will understand what he wants. I think he has a `GPT`. I was not able to fix it yet.

Comment: This link may be helpful for you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/813241/ubuntu-16-04-installation-with-windows-10/814153#814153
But make sure that the partiton is formatted in which you have to install Ubuntu.
This solved My issue,hope so Urs too will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

while you come to partition screen go to last choice something else and next screen you have to make two partitions / and swap.while making / partition select ext4 file system ,format partition and install.down u have boot loader partition  selection .Put it to first partition sda1.when re booting you get grub menu .

Comment: my partition sda1 is for win7. i had done like u said before. by doing the two partition but i choose ext3. and for the boat loader i put the partition for ubuntu. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try following [this tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony) and let me know if that works or not.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: And provide this type of answer as comment until OP confirm that this is the correct solution. Then, you can explain things in an answer.