# Ubuntu 16.04 Installation with Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, windows-10

I have installed Windows 10 in My Dell Inspiron 620s.

When installation of the Ubuntu 16.04.1 64-bit is installed(first time) and when I restarted the system after the fresh installation of Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10.

It started the system in Windows itself without any selection screen of the O.S.

Note:
My system's BIOS mode is Legacy(don't know it will be handy or not.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows 10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/668395/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10)

Comment: you can try by changing BIOS mode to UEFI.

Comment: This link can help you.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: I had installed Windows 10 first & than Ubuntu 16.04 which worked perfectly in another system.@Anwar
How can I change BIOS mode to UEFI@Krishna

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with "Installing Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10"

Previoulsy I was selecting "Select another location"